# Why are there two np.int64s in numpy.core.numeric._typelessdata (Why is numpy.int64 not numpy.int64?)

Tags: python, numpy

This isn't as much of a problem as a curiosity.

In my interpreter on 64 bit linux I can execute

```
In [10]: np.int64 == np.int64
Out[10]: True

In [11]: np.int64 is np.int64
Out[11]: True
```

Great, just what I would expect.
However I found this weird property of the numpy.core.numeric module

```
In [19]: from numpy.core.numeric import _typelessdata

In [20]: _typelessdata
Out[20]: [numpy.int64, numpy.float64, numpy.complex128, numpy.int64]
```

Weird why is numpy.int64 in there twice? Lets investigate.

```
In [23]: _typelessdata[0] is _typelessdata[-1]
Out[23]: False
In [24]: _typelessdata[0] == _typelessdata[-1]
Out[24]: False
In [25]: id(_typelessdata[-1])
Out[25]: 139990931572128
In [26]: id(_typelessdata[0])
Out[26]: 139990931572544
In [27]: _typelessdata[-1]
Out[27]: numpy.int64
In [28]: _typelessdata[0]
Out[28]: numpy.int64
```

Whoah they are different. What is going on here? Why are there two np.int64's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4ed1587a7de85b4fa01dff8ef6e0e901a25f149c/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1655-L1660) are the lines where `_typelessdata` is constructed within `numeric.py`:

```
_typelessdata = [int_, float_, complex_]
if issubclass(intc, int):
    _typelessdata.append(intc)

if issubclass(longlong, int):
    _typelessdata.append(longlong)
```

`intc` is a C-compatible (32bit) signed integer, and `int` is a native Python
integer, which may be either 32bit or 64bit depending on the platform.

- On a 32bit system the native Python `int` type is also 32bit, so
  `issubclass(intc, int)` returns `True` and `intc` gets appended to `_typelessdata`,
  which ends up looking like this:

  ```
  [numpy.int32, numpy.float64, numpy.complex128, numpy.int32]
  ```

  Note that `_typelessdata[-1] is numpy.intc`, not `numpy.int32`.
- On a 64bit system, `int` is 64bit, and therefore `issubclass(longlong, int)` returns `True` and a `longlong` gets appended to `_typelessdata`, resulting in:

  ```
  [numpy.int64, numpy.float64, numpy.complex128, numpy.int64]
  ```

  In this case, as Joe pointed out, `(_typelessdata[-1] is numpy.longlong) == True`.

---

The bigger question is *why* the contents of `_typelessdata` are set like this.
The only place I could find in the numpy source where `_typelessdata` is
actually used is [this line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4ed1587a7de85b4fa01dff8ef6e0e901a25f149c/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1715) within the definition for [`np.array_repr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_repr.html)
in the same file:

```
skipdtype = (arr.dtype.type in _typelessdata) and arr.size > 0
```

The purpose of `_typelessdata` is to ensure that `np.array_repr` correctly prints the string representation of arrays whose `dtype` happens to be the same as the (platform-dependent) native Python integer type.

For example, on a 32bit system, where `int` is 32bit:

```
In [1]: np.array_repr(np.intc([1]))
Out[1]: 'array([1])'

In [2]: np.array_repr(np.longlong([1]))
Out[2]: 'array([1], dtype=int64)'
```

whereas on a 64bit system, where `int` is 64bit:

```
In [1]: np.array_repr(np.intc([1]))
Out[1]: 'array([1], dtype=int32)'

In [2]: np.array_repr(np.longlong([1]))
Out[2]: 'array([1])'
```

The `arr.dtype.type in _typelessdata` check in the line above ensures that printing the `dtype` is skipped for the appropriate platform-dependent native integer `dtypes`.

Comment: So the reason I came across this is because I always wanted the dtype to be printed out for my numpy strings. I couldn't find a flag for it so I ended up slightly modifying array_repr to take a 'force_dtype=False flag'. And then I altered the check to 'if skipdtype and not force_dtype:'.  Is there a reason why native types should not be in the string representation? Is an int64 truly different than a longlong on my system? Also why is repr(np.longlong) = "<type 'numpy.int64'>" to begin with?

Comment: I'd guess that omitting the `dtype` from the string representation of arrays containing native types was probably just a stylistic choice to be consistent with the way native Python scalars are represented. I can't think of any important differences between an `np.int64` and an `np.longlong` on your system, but as Joe mentioned, on another system the C compiler might define a `long long` as something wider than 64bits, so the two types might not always be strictly interchangeable.

Comment: Presumably, `repr(np.longlong) == "<type 'numpy.int64'>"` reflects the fact that (at least on your system) these two types are effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full history behind it, but the second `int64` is actually `numpy.longlong`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from numpy.core.numeric import _typelessdata

In [3]: _typelessdata
Out[4]: [numpy.int64, numpy.float64, numpy.complex128, numpy.int64]

In [5]: id(_typelessdata[-1]) == id(np.longlong)
Out[5]: True
```

`numpy.longlong` is supposed to [directly correspond to C's `long long` type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types). C's `long long` is specified to be at least 64 bits wide, but the exact definition is left up to the compiler.

My guess is that `numpy.longlong` winds up being another instance of `numpy.int64` on most systems, but is allowed to be something different if the C complier defines `long long` as something wider than 64 bits.

Comment: On a 32bit system `_typelessdata == [numpy.int32, numpy.float64, numpy.complex128, numpy.int32]`, so the last element definitely doesn't correspond to `numpy.longlong`

Comment: @ali_m - That's a coincidence of the way `_typeless_data` is constructed. See: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1655 On a 32-bit system, the last item is `np.intc`, and `np.longlong` isn't included in that list.